How to Mask My VPN Server Using VLESS Reality and Avoid Detection?
I bought a cheap server in Sweden, installed x-ui, and set up Xray VLESS Reality for traffic masking. I read that I can use the RealiTLScanner program to find suitable servers for masking, but all the IP addresses in my subnet belong to my provider, which can easily be verified through WHOIS.
I have a couple of questions:

How can I find a server to mask under, if all nearby IP addresses belong to the same provider?

How does traffic masking work with Xray VLESS Reality? If I mask my server as google.com, Wireshark will show that I’m connecting to my own server, and WHOIS on my IP address will indicate that it’s not related to Google. Won’t this give me away?


I would appreciate any insights or suggestions!
